# How to validate multiple fields together?

Tags: react-hook-form

I could not find anything in the doc or issues except for form-level validation not being possible.

I have several fields that I need to validate together and return 1 error message. When I return an error value from resolver for something that is not a field, then then `errors` does not contain it.

Is it possible to achieve something like this with the library? If not, can you suggest a hook library that can?

Comment: have you checked out the validate function in the register, you can use getValues() to reach other input's values as well and hence apply validation accordingly? option 2 just use schema validation.

Comment: @Bill I have access to all values within the resolver function and I am returning error message for a property that has no associated field that means the error is not propagated to the `errors` object of the hook result.

Comment: have you taken at the `schema` validation? that may be what you looking for, also it's a question when you want to validate those filed values, it can be at submit or an input level.